# Spring Integration JSON to JSON transformation

Tags: json, spring-integration

I am building an application with Spring Integration and I'm trying to figure out if there is an example out there of how a JSON can be transformed to another JSON.

The steps would be

```
   1.) extract fields of interest from current JSON
   2.) perform logic if required (split values, concatenate, etc..)
   3.) set the value in the new JSON format
```

I would also like to make this available to the Business Analysts, so that they can make the mapping changes, once the framework is setup.

Cheers
Kris

Answer (score 1):

Well, any JSON can simply be deserialized to `Map`:

```
new JsonToObjectTransformer(Map.class)
```

after that you can apply any filters to map keys, build a new `Map` with new desired keys and serialize it into JSON back:

```
new ObjectToJsonTransformer()
```

Comment: I was actually trying to build the transformed payload with a JSONObject...but can't get it to work yet. The expressions are not being evaluated  <bean id="event" class="org.json.JSONObject" scope="prototype">
  <constructor-arg>
   <util:map>
    <entry key="rNumber" value="#jsonPath(payload, '$.code')" />
    <entry key="createdDateUtc" value="#jsonPath(payload, '$.createdDateUtc')" />
   </util:map>
  </constructor-arg>
 </bean>

Comment: First: that is fully different story and not related to your original question about architecture decision. Second: as you see the code isn't readable in the comment. Please, move it into your question and provide more info what you need to do and what you have tried so far.

Comment: apologies. I replied in a post.